# Reenable button onClick

Tags: javascript

I tried to disable my button with an onClick function using this:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onClick = null;
```

How can I reenable it back again?
example:

```
if(some condition)
  document.getElementById("btn").onClick = null;
else
  //reenable it again
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**disable**

```
document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
```

**enable**

```
document.getElementById("btn").disabled=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is that  save old onclick's method to value (`tempFn`). Then you can reenable again.

```js
var tempFn;
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function () {
    if (!tempFn) {//some condition
        tempFn = document.getElementById("btn").onclick;
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = null;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = tempFn;
        tempFn = null;
    }
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
    alert("btn");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">btn</div>
<button id="btn2">Disable/Enable</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it with jquery

```
    $(function(){
         if(smth){
          //Set button disabled
          $("#btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}else{
     $("#btn").removeAttr("disabled");  
}
```

Comment: are you answering with jquery?